# data segment containing heap data or static variables

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I was reading (Operating System - *Tannenbaum, page 190*) about system memory and I found a paragraph that said:

> the data segment being used as a heap for the variables that are dynamically allocated and released and a stack segment for the normal local variables and return addresses.

Where as [Data Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) says that it is used for initialized static variables.

Which one of them is correct? Or is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Both. Following the initialized static data is the heap. Often first follows the _uninitialized_ static/global data before the heap starts, so: initialized global data; uninitialized global data; heap .... stack (stack grows down and heap grows up).

Answer (score 2):

From your [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) itself:

> Historically, to be able to support memory address spaces larger than the native size of the internal address register would allow, early CPUs implemented a system of segmentation whereby they would store a small set of indexes to use as offsets to certain areas. The Intel 8086 family of CPUs provided four segments: **the code segment, the data segment, the stack segment and the extra segment**.

Now, Operating Systems: Design and Implementation was [written in 1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_Systems:_Design_and_Implementation), When the data segment was used for both stack, heap, initialized data, and uninitialized data.

Since then, there were a few important changes:

- There's no a lot more memory and many more CPU bits, and segmentation is no longer needed by the hardware.
- Segments because more than a mere hardware artifact - they became a memory management design pattern.
- The [BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment was [introduced](https://linux.die.net/man/3/end).
- Features like [`mmap()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) and [POSIX shared memory IPC](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_346) mean that the heap is not a single contiguous segment.
- Multi-threading means multiple stacks, in the same memory space, sharing a single heap.

So when the book was written, the "data segment" was a concept defined by the hardware, and it was defined to contain everything that wasn't local: initialized data, uninitialized data, dynamically allocated data etc.

But these days the OS' memory manager defines "data segement" as "memory area containing the program's initialized data".

On CPUs that use a data segment pointer, it points to the beginning of what the OS' memory manager declares to be "the data segment".

But the memory manager has more segments, for BSS and heap, which aren't represented by a CPU pointer, so the memory manager just places them immediately after the data segment.

Stacks are a different story these days. When you create a new thread, it gets a new stack, often limited in size (e.g. 8 MB on some versions of Linux). Most likely, the stack for a thread will be allocated from the same area as the heap, meaning at a higher address than the data segment, and since the stack grows to *lower* addresses, all stacks will [still grow towards the data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Stack).